# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

i am trying to convert a String to an xml document but i get this error 
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed
This is the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><paragraph><Sentence>?</Sentence><Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence></paragraph>

<paragraph><Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence>
<Sentence>VIENNE - Six alpinistes - cinq Tchèques et un Slovaque - ont péri dans une avalanche près de la station de ski de Sölden dans les Alpes autrichiennes, fait savoir la police d&apos;Innsbruck.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Des témoins ont assisté à l&apos;avalanche, samedi dans le secteur du Schalfkogel, sommet qui culmine à 3.540 mètres dans le massif de l&apos;Ötztal au Tyrol.</Sentence> <Sentence>Ils ont alerté les secours de haute montagne, qui n&apos;ont pu atteindre les lieux que dimanche matin en raison du mauvais temps.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Le Schalfkogel se trouve dans un secteur isolé, au sud-ouest d&apos;Innsbruck, entre les stations de montagne de Sölden et d&apos;Obergurgl, non loin de la frontière italienne.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Le seul rescapé du groupe est un Tchèque d&apos;âge moyen qui avait choisi de rester dans un refuge et a permis d&apos;identifier ses camarades défunts.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Les Alpes autrichiennes ont connu cet hiver des chutes de neige inhabituellement fortes et les avalanches ont été fréquentes et parfois meurtrières, tuant surtout des skieurs qui faisaient du hors piste.</Sentence></paragraph>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will ever have such issues, use xml validator, like:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp
In my opinion you need some kind of a container for your whole xml. Please add an additional tag for instance `<container>` right after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and do not forget to close this tag at the end.

Whole xml would look like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container>
   <paragraph>
      <Sentence>?</Sentence>
      <Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence>
   </paragraph>
   <paragraph>
      <Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence>
      <Sentence>VIENNE - Six alpinistes - cinq Tchèques et un Slovaque - ont péri dans une avalanche près de la station de ski de Sölden dans les Alpes autrichiennes, fait savoir la police d'Innsbruck.</Sentence>
      <Sentence>Des témoins ont assisté à l'avalanche, samedi dans le secteur du Schalfkogel, sommet qui culmine à 3.540 mètres dans le massif de l'Ötztal au Tyrol.</Sentence>
      <Sentence>Ils ont alerté les secours de haute montagne, qui n'ont pu atteindre les lieux que dimanche matin en raison du mauvais temps.</Sentence>
      <Sentence>Le Schalfkogel se trouve dans un secteur isolé, au sud-ouest d'Innsbruck, entre les stations de montagne de Sölden et d'Obergurgl, non loin de la frontière italienne.</Sentence>
      <Sentence>Le seul rescapé du groupe est un Tchèque d'âge moyen qui avait choisi de rester dans un refuge et a permis d'identifier ses camarades défunts.</Sentence>
      <Sentence>Les Alpes autrichiennes ont connu cet hiver des chutes de neige inhabituellement fortes et les avalanches ont été fréquentes et parfois meurtrières, tuant surtout des skieurs qui faisaient du hors piste.</Sentence>
   </paragraph>
</container>
```

Comment: thank you Tomek i have just added <article> </article> and  it works

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 root elements in that xml file:

```
<paragraph><Sentence>?</Sentence><Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence></paragraph>
```

and

```
<paragraph><Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence>
<Sentence>VIENNE - Six alpinistes - cinq Tchèques et un Slovaque - ont péri dans une avalanche près de la station de ski de Sölden dans les Alpes autrichiennes, fait savoir la police d&apos;Innsbruck.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Des témoins ont assisté à l&apos;avalanche, samedi dans le secteur du Schalfkogel, sommet qui culmine à 3.540 mètres dans le massif de l&apos;Ötztal au Tyrol.</Sentence> <Sentence>Ils ont alerté les secours de haute montagne, qui n&apos;ont pu atteindre les lieux que dimanche matin en raison du mauvais temps.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Le Schalfkogel se trouve dans un secteur isolé, au sud-ouest d&apos;Innsbruck, entre les stations de montagne de Sölden et d&apos;Obergurgl, non loin de la frontière italienne.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Le seul rescapé du groupe est un Tchèque d&apos;âge moyen qui avait choisi de rester dans un refuge et a permis d&apos;identifier ses camarades défunts.</Sentence>
<Sentence>Les Alpes autrichiennes ont connu cet hiver des chutes de neige inhabituellement fortes et les avalanches ont été fréquentes et parfois meurtrières, tuant surtout des skieurs qui faisaient du hors piste.</Sentence></paragraph>
```

There must be exactly 1 root element in a [well-formed xml document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document). You need to save those `<paragraph>` elements to individual files or add a root element around those `<paragraph>` elements, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <paragraph>
        <Sentence>?</Sentence>
        <Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence>
    </paragraph>

    <paragraph>
        <Sentence>Une avalanche fait six morts dans les Alpes autrichiennes</Sentence>
        <Sentence>VIENNE - Six alpinistes - cinq Tchèques et un Slovaque - ont péri dans une avalanche près de la station de ski de Sölden dans les Alpes autrichiennes, fait savoir la police d&apos;Innsbruck.</Sentence>
        <Sentence>Des témoins ont assisté à l&apos;avalanche, samedi dans le secteur du Schalfkogel, sommet qui culmine à 3.540 mètres dans le massif de l&apos;Ötztal au Tyrol.</Sentence> 
        <Sentence>Ils ont alerté les secours de haute montagne, qui n&apos;ont pu atteindre les lieux que dimanche matin en raison du mauvais temps.</Sentence>
        <Sentence>Le Schalfkogel se trouve dans un secteur isolé, au sud-ouest d&apos;Innsbruck, entre les stations de montagne de Sölden et d&apos;Obergurgl, non loin de la frontière italienne.</Sentence>
        <Sentence>Le seul rescapé du groupe est un Tchèque d&apos;âge moyen qui avait choisi de rester dans un refuge et a permis d&apos;identifier ses camarades défunts.</Sentence>
        <Sentence>Les Alpes autrichiennes ont connu cet hiver des chutes de neige inhabituellement fortes et les avalanches ont été fréquentes et parfois meurtrières, tuant surtout des skieurs qui faisaient du hors piste.</Sentence>
    </paragraph>
</root>
```